# How to get the sum of a list of structures?

Tags: vb.net

I have a structure defined like this:-

```
Public Structure MyStructure

    ' Some member variables and methods

    Public Shared Operator +(ByVal str1 As MyStructure, ByVal str2 As MyStructure) As MyStructure
        ' Some works
        Return New MyStructure (some parameters)
    End Operator

End Structure
```

And I am using this in a List:-

```
Dim my_list As List (Of MyStructure)
' code to fill in list
```

I'd like to calculate the sum of the structures in the list according to the definition of the overloaded + operator; something like:-

```
Dim my_sum As MyStructure = my_list.Sum(Function(x) x)
```

but this doesn't work because the return type isn't double, single, integer, decimal, long, or a nullable version of one of these. Is there any way to 'get at' the overloaded `+` operator in the Sum method? Some interface to implement, perhaps?

**Edit** It has been suggested that this is a possible duplicate of [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785403/vb-net-linq-query-getting-the-sum-of-all-values-for-a-specific-structure-member?lq=1). That isn't the case; that question asks for the sum of a member variable; this question is asking for the sum as defined by the overloaded `+` operator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET LINQ Query: Getting The Sum of All Values For A Specific Structure Member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785403/vb-net-linq-query-getting-the-sum-of-all-values-for-a-specific-structure-member)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it was an adventure, but this are my results:

The existing Sum extensions only provide basic types as results, therefore need a selector. You found that one out, ok.

Now next step for me was to write my own extension supporting your needs.

So i was looking exactly for what you suggested, an interface that requires the implementing class to have an operator of any kind. 
Well there isn't any. You also cannot define such an interface yourself, as operators by nature are static and cannot be overridable.

So next step is to extend sum by a generic type that constrains itself to the type which does have an operator.

Turns out you cannot constrain a generic type to a structure.

So here the code that i got working

So as i understand you wanted to do something like this:

```
Public Class MainClass
    ' ...
    Public Shared Sub Test()
        Dim lsta As New List(Of SomeClass)(New SomeClass() {
                                           New SomeClass(5, 10, 2.5),
                                           New SomeClass(7, 23, 1.2)
                                       }
                                   )
        Dim sum As SomeClass = lsta.Sum(Of SomeClass)()
    End Sub
    ' ...
End Class
```

Now your structure is gonna have to be a class, such as this:

```
Public Class SomeClass
    Public Sub New(x As Int32, y As Int32, c As Double)
        m_iX = x
        m_iY = y
        m_fC = c
    End Sub
    Private m_iX As Int32
    Private m_iY As Int32
    Private m_fC As Double
    Public ReadOnly Property X
        Get
            Return m_iX
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Y
        Get
            Return m_iY
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property C
        Get
            Return m_fC
        End Get
    End Property

    ' Custom operator:
    Public Shared Operator +(a As SomeClass, b As SomeClass) As SomeClass
        Return New SomeClass(a.X + b.X, a.Y + b.Y, a.C * b.C)
    End Operator

    ' This is coming in handy for initializing the first element in your sum
    Public Shared Function NeutralElement() As SomeClass
        Return New SomeClass(0, 0, 1)
    End Function
End Class
```

And finally here the extension:

```
Public Module ListExtension
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function Sum(Of T As SomeClass)(source As IEnumerable(Of SomeClass)) As SomeClass
        ' Note we have to constain T to SomeClass (also SomeClass cannot be a Structure :))
        Dim returnValue As T = SomeClass.NeutralElement()
        For Each el As T In source
            returnValue = returnValue + el
        Next
        Return returnValue
    End Function
End Module
```

I hope this cleared out some issues, ask any questions and,

... have fun implementing it!

Comment: Thanks for your help here. It so happens that the structures I have need to be structures (value types) but your answer may well prove useful in future.